Error #deleted# When Linking MS Access to MySQL remote database
I downloaded most recent ODBC driver from the MySQL website and installed on windows machine.  I am using MS Access 365 Microsoft® Access® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2411 Build 16.0.18227.20082) 64-bit.
When I link a table it works but when I open all the columns say #deleted#.  I found many references to the problem over many years.
I went into the MySql database and changed the BigInt fields to Int and redid the linking and it worked fine.
I also checked the box in Access for supporting BigInt datatype when Linking.
When I check the linked table structure is has int in MS access field type not Large Integer which is what i would have expected.
Any suggestions or ideas how to fix this?
Thanks!
I did the linking as expected and got the error.

I modified the mySQL table making BigInt fields into Int fields and then linked the table.  That worked.  When I look at the Linked table in access the BigInt fields were listed as Int fields.  When the linking was done appears that it is not done correctly by the ODBC driver.
